# Applying pure function to an association, why the square brackets?

Tags: core-language

I'm studying the [wolfram guide](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/34-associations.html) and I'm trying to figure out why the square brackets on the right side:

```
f[#["apples"], #["oranges"]] &[<|"apples" -> 10, "oranges" -> 12, 
  "pears" -> 4|>]
```

I've also tried to write a simpler one:

```
#["apples"] &[<|"apples" -> 10|>]
```

But without the brackets

```
#["apples"] & <|"apples" -> 10|>
```

it gives the following result:

```
<|"apples" -> 10 (#1["apples"] &)|>
```

(how should I read this result?)

Comment: the last example is syntactically the same as `scale <| “a” -> 10 |>`, which multiplies all entries of the association by `scale`

Comment: `#["apples"] &` is a function (literally the short form of `Function`).  You want to *apply* that function to the association `<|"apples" -> 10|>`.  That can be done like `f[x]` or `f@x`.  Your third code block is like `f x`, which doesn't apply any function, it just multiplies them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand

```
f[#["apples"], #["oranges"]] &[<|"apples" -> 10, "oranges" -> 12, "pears" -> 4|>]
```

break up what you are doing into its parts.

```
assoc = <|"apples" -> 10, "oranges" -> 12, "pears" -> 4|> (* the argument *)
func = assoc |-> f[assoc["apples"],assoc["oranges"]]  (* the function *)
func[assoc] (* apply function to argument *)
```

Comment: If I have well understood if I'd write func = x |-> f[x["apples"],x["oranges"]]  (* the function *) it would work as well, right?

Comment: Could I also formulate it func[x_] := x |-> f[x["apples"], x["oranges"]] ?

Comment: Right: in each case, the variable is local to the function.